# Coschedule / LinkedIn API

Tags: api

A client is using Coschedule to push updates to LinkedIn via their employees' profiles. They noticed recently that Coschedule is giving error messages when they try to push updates to employee pages. The Coschedule technical team did some digging and determined it's an issue with LinkedIn's API, which they believe may have been updated recently (?).

Errors started occurring a couple weeks ago, the app was previously running fine.

They are hoping for more information on LinkedIn's API / how to resolve this as soon as possible as it's generating multiple error message and error emails per employee per day.

Thanks! 
Tia

Answer (score 0):

The outage we saw a few weeks ago was due to LinkedIn depricating the version of OAuth we used to connect LinkedIn profiles/company pages to Calendars. We've since switched to OAuth2, and if your client or your team is still having issues and seeing authentication errors when trying to send out messages, we recommend doing a hard reset of those LinkedIn profiles: https://help.coschedule.com/hc/en-us/articles/216529237-Hard-Reauthentication-for-Social-Profiles-When-Auth-Token-Keeps-Failing#LinkedIn

Best practice is to use an incognito browser window as well.

If you're still getting stuck, reach out to our support channel (support@coschedule.com)and we would be happy to take a closer look!